# Using scanf in C

Tags: c, string, file, while-loop, scanf

My question seems to be very simple but I can't find an answer on Google.

I'd like to know what `while (fscanf(inFile, "%[^ \n] ", string) != EOF)` does.  I'm trying to read in a string from a file by using the above.

However, I am not exactly sure what this statement does, specifically the `%[^ \n]` part.  I know that it will loop until end of file, but is "string" a number value or some other value?  Also, how can I use it?

For example, for a sentence "I like trees", what is the string value equivalent to?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why not read the manual page

Comment: Using `fscanf` to read strings (or character sequences) is quite dangerous and should be avoided. If `char string[buffer_size]` is not large enough to hold the contents, it will overflow and could compromise your system. One could use the POSIX.1-2008 `m` modifier but it's not very portable.

Comment: @codebeard: You can specify length. `%254s`. It is not dangerous if you use it correctly.

Comment: @user13500 You're right – I meant to say that using `fscanf` to read strings of *unknown length* is dangerous. If you specify a field width like `%255[^ \n]` then it's safer, but could still lead to unexpected behaviour and it gets cumbersome to handle the question "did `strlen(string) == 255` because the word was exactly that long, or will my next read string be a continuation of the previous one, and how can I know?"

Comment: @codebeard: If one use `%n`, one can say: `if (items_read > 0 && strlen(string)) > n`. It will be true if whitespace was consumed, as in: `%n` will hold the number of characters read *including* white space.

Answer (score 2):

`%[^ \n]` tells `fscanf` to read all the characters excluding `\n` and `space`.

Comment: So if it reads, "Hello everyone" what is the result.  I mean what is string?

Comment: Will it be "everyone" in the second loop?

Comment: No. It reads one character per iteration. The result after the while loop quits will be only "Hello"

Comment: @aakashjain Is it possible to read different strings per iteration (using some different code)?

Comment: @aakashjain actually the while loop won't ever end in this case, because the end of file is not reached

Comment: It reads more than one character. It could read a billion characters. And the EOF will definitely be reached.

Comment: @codebeard I see, so it reads multiple characters per iteration?

Comment: The claim in this answer is correct, however it is not `%[^ \n]` in the question, rather `%[^ \n] ` with a leading space, as in ajay's answer. **•** It *will* be "everyone" in the second loop, with the code in question. **•** EOF *will* be reached. That leading space will match to and consume every white-space character, including the format-terminator `' '` and `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

Note the space after the caret `^` and the trailing space in the format string `"%[^ \n] "` of `fscanf`.

```
fscanf(inFile, "%[^ \n] ", string)
```

The above statement means that `fscanf` will read from the stream `inFile` and match any nonempty sequence of characters which does not contain either a space `' '` or a newline `'\n'` and write them into the buffer pointer to by the next argument which is `string`, and then read and discard any number of (including zero) whitespace characters (meant by the trailing space in the format string). The buffer pointed to by `string` must be large enough for any such sequence of characters plus the terminating null byte added automatically. If the buffer is not large enough, then `fscanf` will overrun it invoking undefined behaviour and most likely causing program crash due to segfault. You must guard against it by specifying maximum field width which should be one less than the length of the buffer to accommodate the terminating null byte.

`fscanf` returns the total number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which in this case, is one. It will return `EOF` when the end of file is reached in the stream `inFile`. Therefore the `while` loop condition means that `fscanf` will read such a sequence of characters and write it into the buffer `string` till the end of file is reached in the stream `inFile`.

You should change your `while` loop to -

```
// assuming string is a char array

char string[100];

while(fscanf(inFile, "%99[^ \n] ", string) == 1) {
    // return value 1 of fscanf means fscanf call was successful
    // do stuff with string
}
```

Comment: I cannot suggest an edit for this, because it will be a single-character edit. This, however, is important, please change your format string into `"%99[^ \n] "`, with a space right behind the closing double-quote.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin thanks for pointing it out. I had also missed explaining the role of the trailing space in the format string.

Comment: Note that even with this it is impossible to distinguish between a word being longer than 99 characters and a word being exactly 99 characters. That is, if in one iteration you get `string = "aaaa...99...a"` and in the next you get `string = "b"`, you cannot tell if the input was `aaaa...99...ab` or `aaaa...99...a b`. This may or may not be a problem depending on what the string is being used for.

Comment: @codebeard true, but at least this will prevent `fscanf` from overrunning the buffer `string` in case the input is 100 or more characters long. `strlen(string) == 99` is true, then the input was longer with extraneous characters lying in the stream buffer.

Comment: @codebeard cont. and this needs to be dealt with depending on what OP wants to do with it. `fscanf` should not be used if you are not sure that input is formatted.

Comment: @ajay my point is that `strlen(string) == 99` could *also* mean that there are no extra characters and that the word was just exactly 99 characters. And there is no way to distinguish them. For example, if the OP would like to (amongst other things) keep a count of the number of `words++`, then it's impossible to count them properly with this code.

Comment: @codebeard that's true. you must know beforehand the maximum length your word can have else you can't read and count words safely and reliably. I would remove the trailing space from the format string of `fscanf` and add `while((ch = fgetc()) != '\n') { // deal with it}` where `ch` is of type `int`.

Comment: note: this loop "fix" doesn't make sense either, as it will read only one entry. you have to consume the whitespace(s).

Answer (score 0):

`"%[^ \n]"` basically it matches every thing except a `\n` or a `' '` character.

The `fscanf` statement you have will read everything from the file pointed to by `inFile` and then stores what it read into a string named `string`, which should be declared as `char string[500]` (or a similar sufficiently large value). Everytime it successfully reads a character, it returns it.

Now since you need a way for the `while` loop to quit after reading the file, you are comparing the return of `fscanf` to `EOF`, which is the special end-of-file character.

EDIT: corrected `const char*`

Comment: Note that mine has a space after '[' and before '\'.  Is this any different?

Comment: `string` must not be declared as `const char *string`. `string` must be a buffer large enough to hold any sequence of non-space/non-newline characters found, which I might note is *very insecure*.

Comment: So, in my example "I like trees", will string be different each loop?

Comment: @aakashjain So, in my example "I like trees", will string be different each loop?

Comment: No. The while loop after finishing will have read only "I" into string.

Comment: @aakashjain `%[^ \n]` will read a sequence of characters, not just one.

Comment: @user13500 I never said it should be `const`, that was part of the author's post (now corrected). I was saying that it shouldn't be `const`.

Answer (score 0):

`while (fscanf(inFile, "%[^ \n] ", string) != EOF)` has huge problems.

The format string `"%[^ \n] "` is made up of 2 directives:  `"%[^ \n]"` and `" "`.

`"%[^ \n]"` is a format specifier made up of a scanset.  The scanset consists of all `char` *except* `' '` and `'\n'`.  So `fscanf()` looks for 1 or more characters that are in the scanset and saves them to `string`.

`"%[^ \n]"` has 2 problems:
1) If the first character encountered is not in the scanset, `fscanf()` *ungets* that character back to `inFile` and the function returns 0.   No further scanning occurs.  So if `inFile` begins with a `' '`, code puts nothing in `string`, `inFile` is not advanced and subsequent code is set up for UB or an infinite loop!

2) The numbers of characters to save in `string` is unbounded.  So if `inFile` begins with more that the `sizeof(string)-1` `char` in the scanset, undefined behavior ensues.

`" "` directive tells `fscanf()` to consume 0 *or more* white-space `char`.  This can be confusing should `inFile` have the value `stdin`.  In that case, the user needs to enter  some non-white-space *after* the `' '` or `'\n'`.  Since `stdin` is usually line buffered, that means something like `"abc\ndef\n"` needs to be entered before `scanf()` saves `"abc"` and returns 1.  The `"def\n"` is still in `stdin`.

Recommend instead:

```
char string[100];
while (fscanf(inFile, "%99s", string) == 1) {
  ...
}
```

`"%99s"` will consume optionally *leading* white-space, then up to 99 non-white-space `char`, appending the usual `\0`.

Comment: Believe you might meant to say ` == 1` or ` > 0`, not ` != 1`.